# is there a css selector of all siblings of a certain type?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have 3 inputs,2 `type="text"` and 1 `type="button"`

Is there a way to select all siblings of the button that are type text?

for example on button hover to apply `background: yellow;` to its text siblings.

```css
li input{
  margin:3px;
}
li [type="button"]{
  background:red;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
li:hover [type="button"]{
  background:white;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="BUTTON"> 
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS can process only "future" elements from current one, so you can not select ["previous siblings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector).

---

I also suggest using classes, but it's up to you.

---

You can select following siblings with `~` and put elements in reverse:

```css
[type="button"]:hover ~ [type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="button"/>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

---

Better solution: apply hover on parent:

```css
.wrapper:hover [type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="button"/>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: i understood the first part,i just dont quite understand how its a better solution to apply hover on parent,since i want to apply styles only when the button is hovered,not the whole family

Comment: If you really don't want to use a wrapper, you can use flexbox and order.
Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rc09joe6/

Comment: @BunyamiN But... you still use wrapper. `<ol>` is wrapper for `<li>`!

Comment: @Justinas Yes I can remove the `<ol>` but than the `<li>` becomes the wrapper, which you will need to make it work with flex. I agree that using hover on a parent is better solution here.